# How to fetch only 3 data from database table in cyclic order?

Tags: php

I want to fetch only 3 data from database table when any user login.And after that when the next user login the next 3 question will come. How can I do this? What changes should I made in SELECT query?

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM questiontypes";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$qset = "";
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $qset .='<li id="qtypeli">'.$result['qtname'].'</li>';
    $sql1 = "select questions .* from questions where qtype='".$result['qtname']."'order by RAND() LIMIT 3";
    $query1 = mysql_query($sql1);
    while($result1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
        $qset .='<li id="'.$result1['qid'].'" qt="'.$result1['qtid'].'"><span class="qnamespan"> '.$i.'. '.$result1['qname'].'</span></li>
```

Comment: Either include what you have done so far or some minimal understanding of the issue to solve or you ll probably get the question closed.

Comment: show what you tried already

Comment: #chirag--I had used the above code but it shows 3 random questions. My intension is to fetch questions in cyclic order like if any user logs in he will get 1st 3 questions after that when for another user next 3 question will come and so on.

Answer (score 1):

you can set a field in table called taken, in first time the 3 rows taken should be updated with the value 1 in taken field,rest rows will have null in taken. when second time just get the row with max id which has taken=1, increment that id by 1 and get next 3 rows from that id, after getting set the new 3 rows of taken 1 and remove 1 from old 3 rows thats the logic you can apply